# How to figure out if each file is added, modified or deleted in a commit?

Tags: git

If I already the hash of the commit, and need to know which files are added, which are modified and which are deleted at this commit, what should I do?

Let me be specific. In commit `6128373`, `added1.txt` was newly added, `modified.txt` was modified and `deleted.txt` was deleted.

I tried `git show` , and the output is below. It does have what I want, but there are too much unwanted detail, like line-to-line differences.

```
$ git show 6128373                                              
commit 61283738b68b3e9e8d06dc5b9fdb722a43fe33cb (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Wed Jun 23 17:35:17 2021 +0800                          
                                                                
    add modify delete                                           
                                                                
diff --git a/added1.txt b/added1.txt                            
new file mode 100644                                            
index 0000000..53bf775                                          
--- /dev/null                                                   
+++ b/added1.txt                                                
@@ -0,0 +1 @@                                                   
+added                                                          
\ No newline at end of file                                     
diff --git a/deleted.txt b/deleted.txt                          
deleted file mode 100644                                        
index e69de29..0000000                                          
diff --git a/modified.txt b/modified.txt                        
index d8263ee..1234e84 100644                                   
--- a/modified.txt                                              
+++ b/modified.txt                                              
@@ -1 +1,2 @@                                                   
-2                                                              
\ No newline at end of file                                     
+2                                                              
+3                                                              
\ No newline at end of file
```

I tried `git log 6128373`, and the output is below. It does not have what I want, and it shows commits that I don't care about.

```
commit 61283738b68b3e9e8d06dc5b9fdb722a43fe33cb (HEAD -> master)
Author: 
Date:   Wed Jun 23 17:35:17 2021 +0800

    add modify delete

commit 044e02554997346accf215b3c8022e15751973d9
Author: 
Date:   Wed Jun 23 17:34:42 2021 +0800

    a
...
...
```

I tried

```
$ git diff --name-only 6128373~ 6128373
added1.txt
deleted.txt
modified.txt
```

and it doesn't show which files are added|deleted|modified

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+file+added+modified+deleted+commit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing to include `--name-status` option

Reference : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---name-status

`--name-status`

Show only names and status of changed files. See the description of the --diff-filter option on what the status letters mean. Just like --name-only the file names are often encoded in UTF-8.

Example

```
git show --name-status <commitID>
```